# Updating a legacy MapsV2 Eclipse app to latest APIs

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have an old MapsV2 app, which I developed many years ago in Eclipse, and which is live on the Play store. I wish to update the app, however I'm running into a few problems:

1) I have to compile the app using min. API 28, to comply with the terms of the store. In Eclipse, there doesn't seem to be a GoogleAPIs package beyond version 23. Does an API 28 version of GoogleAPIs exist, and if so how can I install it?

If the answer to Q1 is "you can't", then I have this problem:

2) I've tried converting the project to run in Android Studio. I've created a basic sample Maps project, but can't get my old live maps api key to work. I created a licensed build using the original keystore, with the live API key, but when I tested it the maps don't load.

I'm hoping someone with knowledge of migrating an old Maps app to the latest Android APIs can help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you built your app, Google Maps started being distributed differently,

Here's a repository that maintains Eclipse library google-play-services, where Google Maps is
https://github.com/dandar3/android-google-play-services-measurement-base

It's targeting API 28, and you can use it in an app targeting API 28. And check the dependencies. They are available in the same GitHub account,
https://github.com/dandar3

The author also published a post on how to use Eclipse ADT targeting API 27. You can try with API 28, since he's using Platform Tools 28
https://dandar3.blogspot.com/2018/04/android-sdk-for-eclipse-adt.html?m=1

Nevertheless, sooner or later you should migrate your app to Android Studio, and Gradle.

The API key issue is unrelated with the migration process. Check your Maps account and confirm that the package name match the key, and that you're signing the app with the correct certificate.

Comment: Don't forget V3 is in Beta! And it's delivered as a standalone static library and not as part of Play Services. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration